# Regex splits more than once

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I wrote this regex (in python 3): `(?<![\u0410-\u042F])([.!?])(?=(\s)?(\s)?[\u0410-\u042F]|[\u04E8]|["]|[\u201C]|![0-9])`

I use python's `re.split()`

It splits sentences in cyrillic. They're separated by `\n`. So it is supposed to split this:

```
Мамлекеттик айыптоочу Биринчи май райондук сотуна берген бул сунушун диний кастыкты ырбатпоо аракети менен негиздеди. Мусулмандарга акаарат келтирип жатат деген кайрылуу каттын негизинде УКМК Тезекбаевге каршы кылмыш ишин козгоп, сотко өткөргөн. Бул ишти бүгүн Биринчи май райондук соту карап бүттү жана өкүм эртең чыгарыларын маалымдады.
```

to separate sentences:

```
Мамлекеттик айыптоочу Биринчи май райондук сотуна берген бул сунушун диний кастыкты ырбатпоо аракети менен негиздеди.
Мусулмандарга акаарат келтирип жатат деген кайрылуу каттын негизинде УКМК Тезекбаевге каршы кылмыш ишин козгоп, сотко өткөргөн.
Бул ишти бүгүн Биринчи май райондук соту карап бүттү жана өкүм эртең чыгарыларын маалымдады.
```

But for some reason the period (last character) is put on a new line!! Except for the last one.

I see that they say to not put `"()"` around `[.!?]` but if I do that then the punctuation is removed.

Comment: Presumably you are also printing each element in the result list separately, or you are using a `'\n'.join()`, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method would be to re-attach the captured punctiation back onto the preceding element in the list:

```
example = 'Мамлекеттик айыптоочу Биринчи май райондук сотуна берген бул сунушун диний кастыкты ырбатпоо аракети менен негиздеди. Мусулмандарга акаарат келтирип жатат деген кайрылуу каттын негизинде УКМК Тезекбаевге каршы кылмыш ишин козгоп, сотко өткөргөн. Бул ишти бүгүн Биринчи май райондук соту карап бүттү жана өкүм эртең чыгарыларын маалымдады.'

def reattach(sentences):
    punctuation = ('.', '!', '?')
    previous = ''
    for sentence in sentences:
        if sentence not in punctuation:
            previous = sentence
        else:
            yield previous + sentence
            previous = ''
    if previous:
        yield previous

punctuation = re.compile('(?<![\u0410-\u042F])([.!?])(?=(\s)?(\s)?[\u0410-\u042F]|[\u04E8]|["]|[\u201C]|![0-9])')
for sentence in reattach(punctuation.split(example)):
    print(sentence)
```

Running that method on your example input gives me:

```
Мамлекеттик айыптоочу Биринчи май райондук сотуна берген бул сунушун диний кастыкты ырбатпоо аракети менен негиздеди.
 Мусулмандарга акаарат келтирип жатат деген кайрылуу каттын негизинде УКМК Тезекбаевге каршы кылмыш ишин козгоп, сотко өткөргөн.
 Бул ишти бүгүн Биринчи май райондук соту карап бүттү жана өкүм эртең чыгарыларын маалымдады.
```

Comment: It has an error here: `for sentence in reattach(punctuation.split(input)):` TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Also, why re.compile() instead of re.split() ?

Comment: What is `input` in your case? I tested this with Python 3.3, where `input` is a `str`. The explicit `compile` can make things a little faster, it's otherwise no different from using `re.split()`.

Comment: @user1925847: I've renamed the variable `input` to `example` in my answer, to avoid accidental confusion with the built-in function `input()`.

Comment: @user1925847: Interesting, python 3.2 and earlier have problems with the `r''` raw string I used to define the regular expression pattern. Removing the `r` makes things work in earlier python versions. :-)

Comment: @user1925847: Note that `codepad.org` uses python *2*, not python 3, so it doesn't split there because it's getting UTF-8 byts as input, not a Unicode string.

Comment: Here is a version on codepad suitable for Python 2, using `u''` unicode literals instead, and explicitly encoding to utf-8 to make it work with the specific stdout environment provided by codepad.org: http://codepad.org/aSLDYRQ3